# Transparent text on all frames in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to create a frame that consists of two slides and three lines.
The first line should always be clear, the second one should be transparent on the first slide, but clear on the second slide, and the third line should always be transparent.
Is there some way to make the third line transparent on all slides?

I am using the `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` command as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
Always clear.

\onslide<2>{Transparent on slide 1, clear on slide 2.}

Always transparent.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you can manually change the text color of the third line:

`normal text.fg` is the default text color of normal text, `bg` is the background color. I mixed these two colors according to the definition of `transparent`  from the `beamer` manual:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Always clear.

\onslide<2>{Transparent on frame 1, clear on frame 2.}

\textcolor{bg!85!normal text.fg}{Always transparent.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A perfect solution. Thanks a lot.